# Sylius, add/remove/update associated product

Tags: symfony, sylius

i'm trying to add an associated product or replace it if exists. Here's the code i'm using:

```
/** @var ProductAssociationInterface $association */
$association = $this->associationFactory->createNew();
/** @var ProductAssociationTypeInterface $associationType */
$associationType = $this->associationTypeRepository->findOneBy(['code' => 'similar_products']);
$association->setType($associationType);
if ($similar_product = $this->productRepository->findOneByCode(trim($row['Similar product']), $this->locale)) {
    if (!$association->hasAssociatedProduct($similar_product)) {
        $association->addAssociatedProduct($similar_product);
    }

    if (!$product->hasAssociation($association)) {
        $product->addAssociation($association);
        $this->associationManager->persist($product);

        if (!$this->associationRepository->findOneBy(array('owner' => $similar_product->getId(), 'type' => $associationType->getId()))) {
            $this->associationRepository->add($association);
        }
    };
}
```

but while it's working great if there is no associated product - if there is, or even if it's the same product - it throws a duplicate entry error in "product_association_idx" table and I can't figure why or how to set up the check to see if this product is already associated or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you show us what's in the `hasAssociatedProduct` method? `$association->hasAssociatedProduct($similar_product)`

Comment: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Component/Product/Model/ProductAssociation.php

 public function hasAssociatedProduct(ProductInterface $product): bool
    {
        return $this->associatedProducts->contains($product);
    }

Comment: And if you dump that when adding a 2nd product the same as the one already associated, does it return false?

Comment: yes, it does return false, so it's not working correctly, but don't know how else to check if the $similar_product is already associated with $product. $product->getAssociations() gives a list of the association objects but then again it only has the -> contains() method which takes an association and if I add the $similar_product to it to check - it throws the duplicate entry error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, figured it out myself

```
/** @var ProductAssociationInterface $association */
$association = $this->associationFactory->createNew();
/** @var ProductAssociationTypeInterface $associationType */
$associationType = $this->associationTypeRepository->findOneBy(['code' => 'similar_products']);
$association->setType($associationType);
if ($similar_product = $this->productRepository->findOneByCode(trim($row['Similar product']), $this->locale)) {
    $flag = true;
    foreach($product->getAssociations() as $productAssociation) {
        if ($productAssociation->hasAssociatedProduct($similar_product)) {
            $flag = false;
        }
    }

    if ($flag) {
        $association->addAssociatedProduct($similar_product);
        $product->addAssociation($association);
        $this->associationManager->persist($product);

        if (!$this->associationRepository->findOneBy(array('owner' => $similar_product->getId(), 'type' => $associationType->getId()))) {
            $this->associationRepository->add($association);
        }
    };
}
```